# How-to export NUnit Attributes in one file/report

Tags: .net, visual-studio, testing, reporting

I want to create a summary of a test project C# in VS2022 on .NET fw4.6, which shall contain all the Attributes from NUNIT3 like [Description(" testing something ")]. At best with some templating for the formatting.

A PDF like:

- Fixture 1
- - Attributes listed
- TestCase A
- - Attributes listed
- TestCase B
- - Attributes listed

and so on.

I google quiet extensively with no result at all - not even anything commercial.
So I thought I was on the wrong track, but why should those infos be kept only inside VS2022?

I believe I had this several years ago in JUnit and Jenkins, but now on Azure, I couldn't find anythig there neither.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Who has done this?